# Need help solving a simultaneous quadratic

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I'm having a hard time with simultaneous quadratics. I've got this question and don't know how to start off on solving it. I know how to solve linear simultaneous equations and that's about it.

$$x^2 + y^2 = 25\\
y - 2x = 5$$

Ok, so I've managed to square the second equation and got

$$ (y-2x)(y-2x) = 25 = y^2 -4xy + 4x^2$$

I also find it hard to recognise when a pair of equations is a quadratic. How do I identify when it is a quadratic simultaneous equation?

Comment: Substitution?  Solve for $x$ in the right equation?

Comment: ^ Hey look, its me. Perhaps you could consider adding more information to this one?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt what do you want to know?

Comment: I suppose you could try to show some effort? For example, what happens when you square the second equation and set the 25's equal to each other? You should get$$x^2+y^2=y^2-4xy+4x^2$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt will do, this is a really old question though and I know how to solve these now so even though its kind of redundant I need to get my negative questions up so I'm not barred from asking questions

Comment: (Yeah, same, I can understand. Perhaps check [constructive feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plugging your second equation $$y=5+2x$$ in your first equation we get
$$x^2+(5+2x)^2-25=0$$
expanding and factorizing we have to solve
$$5x(x+4)=0$$
Can you solve the rest?

Comment: Yeah this helps a lot. In future, how can I tell if the simultaneous equations are quadratic?

Comment: if at least one variable is a power of $2$

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated